# Why is it written "art" in our site logo?

Tags: discussion

I'm new here. I saw the site's logo and it is written "art". Why not "CL" for example which is the acronym of *Constructed Languages*? What does the scope of this site have to do with art anyway?

[image: logo]

In other websites that don't have an actual logo like this, there is a related phrase. For example, [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com) has a **Po**, [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com) has an **A**, etc.

Shouldn't our logo get fixed?

I first wanted to take a screensot of main site, but I forgot! :/

Every time I edit the post to add a hi/hello before "I'm new here" it doesn't add! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the motivations behind that choice, but *art* hints at *artificial languages* which is more or less synonymous to *constructed languages*. Maybe the Stackexchange team wanted to avoid some unpleasant connotations, e.g., *con* would remind some people to *con artist* and *cl* is much more frequently translated to *computation linguistics* or something else than to *constructed languages*